# Using an expected value inequality to show convergence

Tags: statistics, random-variables, expected-value

Let (X$_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of random variables defined on a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$.
Suppose that $\mathbb{E}(|X_n|^\frac{3}{2}) < 1/n^\frac{3}{2}$
for all $n \in\mathbb{N}$. Show that $X_n$ converges almost surely
to $0$ as $n \to \infty$.

I'm really confused about how to do this question. I can't see how we use the inequality to show convergence? Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can inspire yourself from the demonstration of the $L^4$ version of the strong law of large number. Here consider the series $\sum | X_n | ^{2/3}$, its sum is well defined as a random variable at values in $[0,+\infty]$, by the Beppo-Levi lemma one can swap the expectation and the series symbol :
$$ \mathbb{E} \left( \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} | X_n | ^{3/2} \right) =\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \mathbb{E} \left(  | X_n | ^{3/2} \right) \leq \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{n^{3/2}}$$
where the last series is convergent. Thus, for almost every $\omega \in \Omega $, $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} | X_n(\omega) | ^{3/2} $ is real and $X_n (\omega)\longrightarrow 0$.